# IntelliJ 15. Run and exclamation mark near class name

Tags: intellij-idea

I see an icon near some classes in IntelliJ IDEA in my project.

[image]

Exclamation mark (in circle) and run near class name - what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that one or all tests in your class was failed.

For more information about this gutters I suggest you to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USmQjjQDqhA).